# Is there a way to create a collection that has an Add method but also has a covariant type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, ienumerable

I need a collection that has an Add method and a covariant type parameter.

IEnumerable of T covers the covariant type parameter

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

but it has no Add method.

IList of T does not have a covariant type parameter but has the Add method.

Does anyone know a collection that would cover this or how to make one?

Answer (score 3):

`IEnumerable<out T>` means that "values of this type can be assigned to a variable of any type `IEnumerable<X>` where `X` is `T` or a parent of `T`"

If you had something like `IList<out T>`, that would mean you could do the following:

```
IList<string> strings = new List<string>();
IList<object> objects = strings; 
objects.Add(new object());
```

Obviously this is not type-safe, which is why no such interface can exist.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot have an interface which is a *co*variant with respect to `T` and includes an an `Add` method that takes type `T`, since one that would imply that a collection which was capable of accepting any type of `Dog` was capable of accepting any type of `Animal`.  One could define a *Contra*variant interface `IFeedable<in T>` with an `Feed` method which took a parameter of type `T` (I prefer "feed" to "add", since the latter term can also refer to an arithmetic operation, and since the existence of an object which can accept objects and do something with them does not imply that those objects are being added to some sort of a collection; for example, one could easily have a filtering class which took an `IFeedable<T>` and a `Predicate<T>` and implemented `IFeedable<T>` by taking every `T` it was given, called the predicate function, and passed the item to the supplied `IFeedable<T>` only if the predicate returned true.  Data given to such a method wouldn't necessarily be "added" to any sort of collection, but would nonetheless be "fed" to the object implementing the interface.